# NUnit TestFixture Execution Question

Tags: database, nunit

I am trying to test some legacy database code.  I have many situations where I want to

1. Set database in empty state

For a group of tests do the following for each group:

1. for a group of tests, set the db to an inital test state
2. run those tests
3. return db back to empty state

In NUnit, when using a TestFixture am I guaranteed that the entire fixture's test will be run together as well as the TestFixtureTearDown before the next TestFixture gets processed?  I've tried this using the Visual Studio test stuff and this doesn't appear to be the case.

The main reason for trying to do this, is that sometimes the process of getting the db to the state in step 2 can be expensive and I don't want to have to run this for each of the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

`TestFixtureTearDown` will be executed once the tests with the `TestFixture` are completed. Coupling this with `TestFixtureSetUp` should provide the beahivor your are seeking on a `TestFixture` basis.

The [Unit Testing Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147%28VS.80%29.aspx) in Visual Studio does not have the same syntax as NUnit. While the test approach is the same for all xUnit based frameworks the syntax will vary.

Comment: Right, but does one TestFixture run all the way through TextFixtureTearDown before another test fixture will start processing?

Comment: @Eric - Yes. TestFixtureSetUp runs once before all tests in that fixture. TestFixtureTearDown runs once after all tests in that fixture.

Comment: But can the execution of two fixtures overlap?  That's what I am really trying to understand.

Comment: @Eric The tests are run in a sequential manner so no overlapping will occur; although I have heard NUnit 3 will have thew ability to run tests in a parallel manner. However keep in mind that if your TestFixtureTearDown makes an async call the TestFixture will complete even though there may be something taking place outside of the TesxtFixture due to the nature of the async call.

Comment: Actually, I have routinely seen nUnit start the next alphabetically named testfixture before finishing the previous.  It has caused a lot of headache for me.